# How to post a message to child window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, postmessage

I have a parent window with used id. From parent opens a child window (child1). The child1 calls web service to aspx page to required data for the used id getting from parent window.

Received message in child window code is:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(ev) {
    alert("message: " + ev.data.message);
});
```

Post message from parent:

```
child1.postMessage({ message: "9988-7854-1752-6301", result: true }, "*");
```

Parent and Child window runs different domain.

Tried `window.postMessage` its working fine in chrome and firfox not working in IE.

Kindly suggest for IE browsers.